# Wordpress sends lots of sleep sql query to mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache

My server got stucked last night because of database connection error.
I investigated it is caused by too many database connections. After a research from google and stackoverflow, I didn't get any useful information. While I am trying to investigate all plugins one by one to see if any of them has a bug or something did this, I would like to ask your helps..

First of all, when I logged in to MySQL I can see a lot of SLEEP queries with NULL info there. I tried to use command line to kill all sleep queries but there still more requests fill all connections right away.

The weird thing is, the apache server is not actually getting high volumn of requests. I am actually using AWS RDS as my database server so the apache and mysql is not on same server. The RDS server doesn't have public access so I am sure all requests are only from my apache server. The cpu usage on apache server is not high. Also, I searched the apache's access_log there are not a lot requests at that time. And I cannot find anything wrong with these requests. Especially there is no requests is performing injection attack. I think it is possible some thing triggered in the code so I searched 'SLEEP' in all my code but can only find some in the w3 total cache plugin, which the code blocks in this plugin is not easily get reached..I turned off the XML-RPC in apache level so it shouldn't be the XML-RPC attack.

I know there are a lots of possibility since I am using about twenty plugins in my site, but it is really weird I cannot find any possible requests caused this on apache level. Is it possible any requests can hit the server without being recorded in access_log?

I am pretty new to configure apache and mysql on my own and still learning these features..Thanks in advance for helping me!

Comment: At a guess sounds like idle peristant connections http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php - the 'quick' way to address it might be decrease `wait_timeout` on mysql server side https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout

Comment: (also are they queries with actual SLEEP() function call, or just 'idle' connections in 'SLEEP' *state*)

Comment: @barryhunter thanks for help! I am trying to set wait_timeout to lower value but it seems not working.. just looked it is a Sleep command which showed from Show Full Processlist; command..

Comment: Were you able to resolve it? I am kinda stuck on same kinda issue, here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409413/mysql-database-query-opening-too-many-processes-randomly and I am suspecting maybe something with the latest release of MariaDB is wrong.