# MySQL database query opening too many processes randomly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a weird situation, I have this long query that is taking normalized data from 4 tables through INNER JOINs:

> SELECT room.nameid, room.name, rent.class, rent.type, rent.id, timings.city, timings.depo, timings.checkout
>   FROM room
>   INNER JOIN customers ON room.nameid = customers.nameid
>   INNER JOIN rent on customers.id = rent.customerid
>   INNER JOIN timings on timings.nameid = room.nameid 
>   WHERE customers.fromcity = 'LONDON' AND customers.tocity = 'MANCHESTER' AND (timings.city='LONDON' OR timings.city='MANCHESTER')

This query works fine for 10-20 times and then randomly for one innocent looking time, creates too many processes at the backend and returns totally empty.

```
show processlist;

+-------+------------------+-----------+-----------------+---------+------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Id    | User             | Host      | db              | Command | Time | State                    | Info                                                                                                 | Progress |
+-------+------------------+-----------+-----------------+---------+------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|     1 | system user      |           | NULL            | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge coordinator | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
|     2 | system user      |           | NULL            | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
|     3 | system user      |           | NULL            | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
|     4 | system user      |           | NULL            | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB purge worker      | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
|     5 | system user      |           | NULL            | Daemon  | NULL | InnoDB shutdown handler  | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
| 47489 | root             | localhost | NULL            | Query   |    0 | init                     | show processlist                                                                                     |    0.000 |
| 73262 | database_other    | localhost | database_other   | Sleep   |    0 |                          | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
| 73264 | database_user | localhost | database_name | Query   |    0 | Sending data             | SELECT rooms.roomid, room.name, rent.class, rent.type, rent.id, timings.city, timings.depo |    0.000 |
| 73271 | database_user | localhost | database_name | Sleep   |  109 |                          | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
| 73272 | database_user | localhost | database_name | Sleep   |  109 |                          | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
| 73273 | database_user | localhost | database_name | Sleep   |  109 |                          | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
| 73274 | database_user | localhost | database_name | Sleep   |  109 |                          | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
| 73275 | database_user | localhost | database_name | Sleep   |  109 |                          | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
| 73276 | database_user | localhost | database_name | Sleep   |  109 |                          | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
| 73277 | database_user | localhost | database_name | Sleep   |  108 |                          | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
| 73278 | database_user | localhost | database_name | Sleep   |  108 |                          | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
| 73279 | database_user | localhost | database_name | Sleep   |  108 |                          | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
| 73280 | database_user | localhost | database_name | Sleep   |  108 |                          | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
| 73281 | database_user | localhost | database_name | Sleep   |  108 |                          | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
| 73282 | database_user | localhost | database_name | Sleep   |  108 |                          | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
| 73284 | database_user | localhost | database_name | Sleep   |  108 |                          | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
| 73285 | database_user | localhost | database_name | Sleep   |  108 |                          | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
| 73286 | database_user | localhost | database_name | Sleep   |  108 |                          | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
| 73287 | database_user | localhost | database_name | Sleep   |  108 |                          | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
| 73288 | database_user | localhost | database_name | Sleep   |  108 |                          | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
| 73289 | database_user | localhost | database_name | Sleep   |  108 |                          | NULL
```

I am just posting a sample, in fact, this process list consists of 408 rows, in each row, the database is same and status is sleep.

Then if you wait for like half a minute and refresh the PHP page, it again starts fetching the results as expected.

The tables are not very lengthy and one successful fetch generally consists on 8-10 rows.

What can be the reason if anyone could point me to the right direction?

UPDATE
Here is the PHP code, it's a Wordpress plugin, I have tried wpdb->showerror, it does not show anything and also tried printing the rows, the variable comes back just empty.

```
$mydb = new wpdb(DATABAE_USER,DATABASE_PASSWORD,DATABASE_NAME,DB_HOST);

function rooms_to_in_func( $atts ) {
$result = '';
$a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'fromcity' => 'LONDON',
        'tocity' => 'MANCHESTER'
    ), $atts );

global $mydb;
$rows = $mydb->get_results("SELECT room.nameid, room.name, rent.class, rent.type, rent.id, timings.city, timings.depo, timings.checkout
                            FROM room
                            INNER JOIN customers ON room.nameid = customers.nameid
                            INNER JOIN rent on customers.id = rent.customerid
                            INNER JOIN timings on timings.nameid = room.nameid 
                            WHERE customers.fromcity = 'LONDON' AND customers.tocity = 'MANCHESTER' AND (timings.city='LONDON' OR timings.city='MANCHESTER')");
if($a['fromcity'] == 'LONDON'){
    echo "rows".$rows;
    if($rows == ""){
        echo "empty";
    }
    print_r($rows);
    echo $mydb->last_error;
    if($mydb->last_error !== '') :
        $mydb->show_errors();
        $mydb->print_error();
        endif;
}
```

**UPDATE**
I ran this query directly with EXPLAIN, here is the result:

> 1 SIMPLE  room    ALL                 90
>   1   SIMPLE  timings ALL                 1681    Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) 
>   1   SIMPLE  rent    ALL                 35701   Using join buffer (incremental, BNL join)
>   1   SIMPLE  customers   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   database.rent.customerid    1   Using where

Comment: can you please provide schemas, raw data sample and expected result set?

Comment: and where are tables schema?

Comment: ...in other words please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: This was WordPress related, I just used existing wpdb global variable to make the database connection instead of creating a new one and the problem went away.